# setting variables names while sending data from java to php

Tags: java, android, apache

hi i have a desktop java app which sends data to a php server.
i have to set variable names while sending data to the server .
i have done it before on android by using this code

```
          HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // post header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwrd));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

now this code is not valid for java desktop app.
for java i am doing this

```
       url = new URL(targetURL);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

     // connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

      connection.setUseCaches (false);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      //Send request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                  connection.getOutputStream ());
      String parameters = "username="+username+"&password="+password;
     // wr.writeBytes (parameters);


      wr.writeChars(parameters);
      wr.flush ();
```

how can i define variables as i was dong in android.
if any one can help i will be thank full.

Comment: `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));` here username is the tag given for the variable username

Comment: yeah but this is in android side i need some thing like this in java desktop app.

Comment: httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
this lines are not supported in java.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial, I hope this would help you. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: aah thanks for helping but this not what i am looking for.i already established connection with android now i need to established it with java app on desktop.and the thing i only don't know is how to set variables on java as i am doing ti on android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Get method instead of post for java

```
try {
        String parameters = "username=" + str1 + "&password=" + str2;
        res = JsonReader
                .excuteGet("http://1.tcesinput.appspot.com/login_s.php?"
                        + parameters);
            }
```

So here **username** and **password** are your variables.